# why a c++ application has three threads started by default?

Tags: c++

There is an empty Windows console C++ application. In my mind, a process would have one thread started by default, but it shows three threads when debugging it. The program as follows:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

and the debug information is:
[image: debug information showing three threads]

Comment: Two of them are system threads. Your program only runs on that first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ntdll.dll` threads are in fact operating system threads started from library you link against. All your code is running on thread 16472.

Usually these are threadpool workers to load other dynamic libraries for your app. Windows 10 is optimizing process startup by utilizing multiple CPU cores to initialize faster.

Comment: Is there an option to disable this optimization and have a console app spin up only the main thread?

Comment: @rsp Sort-of, you can reduce threadpool to 1 thread (yours). See this blogpost for very detailed explanation: https://blogs.blackberry.com/en/2017/10/windows-10-parallel-loading-breakdown